# Add namespace declaration to xml element using xquery

Tags: xquery, basex

I would like to ask about the way to add namespace declaration into an xml element of BaseX database using xquery. 
for example I have the following xml

```
<mynode xmlns:b2t=".."></mynode>
```

And I want ta add one more namespace for example xmlns:b3t=""
in order to get an xml like this

```
<mynode xmlns:b2t=".." xmlns:b3t=".."></mynode>
```

Answer (score 0):

XQuery Update provides no means to add namespace declarations in an existing document. However, namespace declarations will automatically be included if you insert elements or attributes with namespaces.